# Dependency Injection in not working in Spring Application

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a spring project, and as well I have separate package in that project which have rest service code.

Now my doubt is, I have interface and implementation class, which is been successfully called from spring controller class. But when I try to call the interface and implementation class from RestService class, by using @Autowired annotation I am getting null value instead of getting object.

Code is (Not working)

```
@Path("/sampleList")
public class Sample{

    @Autowired  
    public SampleService sampleService;

   @Autowired   
    public SampleVO sampleVO ;

    // This method is called if JSON is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      public SampleVo sayXMLHello() throws Exception {
         DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection();
         MongoClient mongo = null;
         try{
         mongo = dbConnection.mongoDBConnection();
             sampleVO .setEngineNameList(sampleService.someList(mongo));
         }catch(Exception e){
             throw e;
         }finally{
                dbConnection.mongoDBCloseConnection(mongo);
            }
        return sampleVO ;
      }

}
```

Here sampleService and sampleVO returns null value, instead of object.

SampleService interface, SampleServiceImpl , SampleVO  classes

```
@Component
public interface SampleService {
//methods
}

@Component
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {
//methods
}

@Component
public class SampleVO {
//methods
}
```

Servlet context:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sample" />
```

Spring controller package like : com.sample.proj.controller
Rest Class package like : com.sample.proj.serviceapi.controller

Spring config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
     <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean> 

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/bootstrap/" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.proj.serviceapi.controller" />



    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>


</beans:beans>
```

Code Working: (Service and ServiceImpl, VO classes are same as shown above)

```
@Controller
public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    public SampleVO sampleVO;

    @Autowired 
    public SampleService sampleService;


    @RequestMapping(value="/", method =RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView sampleMethod(HttpSession session) throws Exception{

    sampleService.callSomeMethod();

    }
    }
```

Comment: I am confused, can you post the code how the code is for successful scenario (which works) and it is for failure scenario (which fails) clearly?

Comment: You do not need to annotate SampleService with `@Component`, it is an interface. Show your spring configuration, please.

Comment: Remove the second `<context:component-scan .../>`. The first one is going to scan that path as it is subfolder of `com.sample`. Nothing looks wrong at first sight. Are you sure the components you are trying to autowired are under `com.sample`?